# Show pagination and exclude category

Tags: php, wordpress

So, I am trying to show items from a specific category in the woocommerce:

Here is what I have so far:

```
<?php
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'product', 'posts_per_page' => 10, 'product_cat' => '',  'orderby' => 'date', 'order' => 'DESC' );
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); global $product; 
?>

<div class="content"> Content </div>

<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

When the `product_cat` is empty, it shows all the items. I want to include "exclude category".

For example, I want to show all but items in a "no_good" category.

Could someone help me out with it?

Also, how can I add a pagination to this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is `product_cat` your custom taxonomy? If it is then you need to modify your `$args` with [tax query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters):

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'tax' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
            'field' => 'name',
            'terms' => array('no_good'),
            'operator' => 'NOT IN',
        ),
    ),
);
...
```

This assumes that "no_good" is a `product_cat` name. Adjust *field* if it isn't.

Regarding the pagination part, do check the [codex article regarding pagination](https://codex.wordpress.org/Pagination).